# CatiaV5 release 26 VBA Design.Geometrical

Tags: vba, catia

While executing the VBA macro script for the English language the macro works properly. Instead for German language CATIA V5 release 26 it does not work. The error occurs at this point in the code

SelectionRoot.Search "Part Design.Geometrical Set.Name=Attribute,sel"

I think it should be a compartibility issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search syntax is specific to the user interface language the user is using. You have to give the German CATIA words for "Geometrical Set".

Unfortunately it is not simple to determine which language a user is using or switch for running a macro.

I have to detect between English and Japanese and I  can do this by reading the FrameGeneral.CATSettings file, looking for the line which has "UserInterfaceLanguage" in it and measuring the length of the line. If it is 70 that means Japanese. If not we assume English. German might be different.

Comment: True, I agree with your answer but do you have any reference like you found for Japenese language which could help me find out German words for "Geometrical set".

Comment: Start CATIA in German, go to File->Search and figure it out. It's all there.